# LXC 2.0 Ownership problems

Tags: lxc, lxd

If I launch an Ubuntu 16.04 container and install for instance memcached on it, then almost all the processes /proc//* descriptors are owned by nobody.nogroup or 65334.65334

Where as if I would install memcached it on my host machine these would be owned by root.root

In effect I can't see which processes are bound to which ports using netstat, since even root get's permission denied to these files:

On my LXC container: https://pastebin.com/raw/FXp1bcwm
On my host system: https://pastebin.com/raw/LZjuN6iq

What can I do about this?

Comment: I think you have to add a user mapping for the container. Not really sure, but [there](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/06/15/custom-user-mappings-in-lxd-containers/) is some more information about it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are trying to install memcached as 'x' user however, that user ID might not exist or might be different.

A good script could be found here: https://gist.github.com/bloodearnest/ebf044476e70c4baee59c5000a10f4c8